# Canvas | Javascript игра

Tags: javascript, canvas

Управляешь самолетом и собираешь топлива, каждая собранная соплива увеличивает счетчик топлива до 10(единица топлива дает 1сек полета). Нужно что бы когда остается 4 единиц топлива падал следующий бак топлива. попробовал сделать так но когда счетчик топлива уменьшается до 4, страница зависает:

```
var timer = 0;
var gas_score = 10;

function gas_and_timer() {
    gas_score--;
    timer++;
}
setInterval(gas_and_timer,1000);

for(var i = 0; i < par.length; i++) {
    ctx.drawImage(parf, par[i].x, par[i].y, 45, 70);

    par[i].x -= 3;
    par[i].y += 3;

    if(gas_score==4) {
        par.push({
            x : Math.floor(Math.random() * 650) + 450,
            y : -80
        })
    }

    if (xPlane + 170 >= par[i].x
        && xPlane <= par[i].x + 25
        && yPlane + 48 >= par[i].y
        && yPlane <= par[i].y + 45) {
        gas_score = 10;
    }
}
```

попробовал и так, игра идет но топлива не падает:\

```
var timer = 0;
timer++;

if(timer%120==0) {
    par.push({
        x : Math.floor(Math.random() * 650) + 450,
        y : -80
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё, решил проблему вынес из цикла и использовал 2 вариант, теперь топлива падает каждые 360 кадров = 6 сек, таймер увеличивается каждый кадр

```
var timer = 0;

timer++;

if(timer%720==0) {
  par.push({
    x : Math.floor(Math.random() * 650) + 450,
    y : -80
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Цикл

```
for(var i = 0; i < par.length; i++) {
```

никогда не завершится при `gas_score==4`, так как Вы все время добавляете в массив `par`. Вынесите

```
if(gas_score==4) {
    par.push({
        x : Math.floor(Math.random() * 650) + 450,
        y : -80
    })
}
```

из цикла.

Comment: вынес, теперь при счетчике 4, падает 50-60 штук топлива ВТФ?!? if(gas_score==4)

Comment: @NurbekNazarbay Я многое могу, но все-таки я не волшебник. Вы показали обрывок кода, но я смог объяснить Вам причину зависания страницы. Так что "ВТФ?" - надо спросить у Вас.

Comment: окей, окей спасибо за ответ, просто хотел сказать теперь топлива падает целую секунду до 50 штук, пока счетчик не перейдет на 3

Comment: @NurbekNazarbay Из приведенного кода причина этого поведения неясна.